# How to address the inconsistency in output and interrupt the execution of a function in a R program?

Tags: r

Programming Language: R x64 3.2.0

Disclosure: This is a part of a problem from R Programming course offered by Coursera. I am new to the programming language and wrote the following code as a part of the assignment:

In this assignment we had to find the hospital with the lowest 30-day mortality rate, as per the information provided in the data set given.

**Input:** The name of the state (i.e. the acronym provided in the data set) and the "outcome", which is the name of the disease (heart attack, heart failure and pneumonia)

**Output:** The name of the hospital with the lowest 30-day-mortality rate (which is given in a .csv file)

```
check <- function(state, outcome, data)
{


    disease <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
      if(is.element(state, data$State) != TRUE)


{
    print("Invalid State")

  }

  else if(is.element(outcome, disease) != TRUE)
  {
    print("Invalid outcome")


  }

}


best <- function(state, outcome)
{
    dataset <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

  check(state, outcome, dataset)
  if(outcome == 'heart attack')
  {

    temp <- dataset[dataset$State == state, c(2, 11)]
    temp2 <- as.numeric(temp[[2]])
    minimum <- min(temp2, na.rm = TRUE)
    good_hospital <- temp[temp[[2]]== as.character(minimum), 1]

    good_hospital
  }
  else if(outcome == 'heart failure')
  {
    temp <- dataset[dataset$State == state, c(2, 17)]
    temp2 <- as.numeric(temp[[2]])
    minimum <- min(temp2, na.rm = TRUE)
    good_hospital <- temp[temp[[2]]== as.character(minimum), 1]

    good_hospital
  }
  else if(outcome == 'pneumonia')
    {
      temp <- dataset[dataset$State == state, c(2, 23)]
      temp2 <- as.numeric(temp[[2]])
      minimum <- min(temp2, na.rm = TRUE)
      good_hospital <- temp[temp[[2]]== as.character(minimum), 1]

      good_hospital
    }

}
```

1. When I give the input best("MD", "heart attack"), it is giving me the required output i.e. "JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE", but when I give best("AZ", "heart attack"), it is giving character(0). in fact, it is happening for best("TX", "heart attack") as well. I don't understand where I went wrong. 
   (PS: I have not completed the program yet. I have not yet included the code for the cases where there is a tie. But for "AZ" and "TX" with "heart attack", there is no tie. I checked with the data set.)
2. How do I interrupt a function execution? I want to stop the execution of the function check() and stop the execution of the program after one of the cases has been satisfied.

Thanks in advance. 
Dropbox link to the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7qysq8ns5sof27/ProgAssignment3-data.zip?dl=0

Comment: And how do we work on this without the data file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7qysq8ns5sof27/ProgAssignment3-data.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions for improvement of your code:

**1.** You don't really need a separate *check*-function. You can replace the `check(state, outcome, dataset)` line in you best-function with:

```
if(! state %in% dataset$State) stop("invalid state")
if(! outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")) stop("invalid outcome")
```

Those two lines will stop the execution of the function when an invalid value is entered in the function.

**2.** You can simplify the code in the if-else statements as follows:

```
if(outcome == 'heart attack')
{
  temp <- dataset[dataset$State == state, c(2, 11)]
  temp <- temp[order(temp[,2],temp[,1]),]
  return(as.character(temp[1,1]))
}
```

This part first takes the needed columns, then orders them according to the outcome (e.g. *heart attack*) with ties ordered alphabetically. The last line returns the name of the best hospital.

The new *best*-function gives me the following results:

```
> best("TX", "heart attack")
[1] "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER"
> best("AZ", "heart attack")
[1] "MAYO CLINIC HOSPITAL"
> best("MD", "heart attack")
[1] "JOHNS HOPKINS HOSPITAL, THE"
```